# how to find if the excel sheet is opened on system using progress 4GL?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to progress 4GL. I have exported some data as a CSV file format using progress 4GL. The issue I am facing is If I run the program for the first time then CSV file is created but if I run another program by keeping CSV file open on my machine then the data is not written to the same CSV file. Instead it is giving error. I want to use one CSV(sample.csv) file for storing the data from multiple programs.

If it is possible to write the data by keeping CSV file open on my machine then tell me the way or else I want to find that if the file is open(sample.csv) then I need to give a message to a user that "pls close CSV file".

The program I tried from my side. The error I got is attached.

```
OUTPUT TO "C:\Users\ast\Pictures\Saved Pictures\sample.csv".

EXPORT DELIMITER ";" "CustNum" "Name".
FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK:
   EXPORT DELIMITER ";" Cust-Num Name.
END.
OUTPUT CLOSE.
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to the file since Excel (in this case) has a lock on the file.

You can catch the error - it's number is shown in your error message:

```
output to c:\temp\foo.csv.
put unformatted 'lockme'.
output close.

catch e as progress.lang.error:

   if e:getMessageNum(1) = 98 then 
      message 'please close the file' view-as alert-box.
   else
      undo, throw e.

end catch.
```

Comment: I would suggest to add an

ELSE UNDO, THROW e . 

to the IF statement in the CATCH block to re-THROW all other errors.

Comment: Done, I generally prefer skeleton code, but since it may suppress future questions... :-)

Comment: @StefanDrissen I did syntax check but it says incompatible data types in expression or assignment. What can I do?

Comment: e:getMessage(1)  should be e:getMessageNum(1)